# Changing value of element in a new window

Tags: javascript

HelIo. Stuck so hard and need some help. I'm opening a new window by js like that

```
smsWin = window.open(/address", "Address", "width=520, height=250");
```

Opened page got a structure like that

```
<div id="Data" style="margin: 0px; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
    <form name="send_form" action="/send_sms.pl">
        <textarea id="textsms" class="sms" onkeyup="checklength();" onpaste="checklength();" name="text" </textarea>
//the rest of from
```

How can i change the value of that textarea by js? Tried a lot of solutions with document.forms  like

```
document.forms[0].elements['textsms'].value = "smth";
```

or

```
smsWin.getElementById['textsms'].value = "smth";
```

and experiensing errors like .... is null or ... is undefined. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: `getElementById` is a method. You call it with parentheses, not square brackets.

Comment: You're missing an opening quote on `window.open(/address"...);`, and `//` is not an HTML comment. Use `<!-- ... -->`

Comment: i just cut the unused information, of course there is a quote on address. The problem is that value is not changing